# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad

Tags: angular, spring-boot, ionic4

hope this is not a stupid question. 
connecting  ionic and java springboot , there's no error message when the app is live serving in a browser and the data is correctly displaying. But got SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () error when testing on android device.

I searched around and realized the issue is related with JSON parse, but I don't quite understand why there's no error message reported in the browser.

what i m trying to do here:
I have a table User with name and email, and I m connecting to display all the name on front end.The backend returns a List.

I also used chrome CROS extension , but I dont think that is related at all.
could any one help explain ? all thanks

```
   typescript
   ngOnInit() {
      this.surgeonList = [
      ];
      console.log(this.value);
      this.httpclient.get('http://localhost:8080/users'
      ).subscribe(
          data => {
              data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
              for (var i  = 0 ; i < (<Array<any>>data).length; i++) {
                  this.surgeonList.push(
                      {
                          name: data[i].lastname,
                          icon: 'person'
                      }
                  );
              }
          }
      );
  }
```

```
JAVA spring controller

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List getUsers(){
        List users = userRepository.findAll();
        return users;
    }
```

The get request response logs the data correctly:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "lastname": "Liu",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "karen698698@gmail.com",
        "password": "613387"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "lastname": "Liu",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "karen77777",
        "password": null
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "lastname": "Liu",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "karen77777",
        "password": null
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "lastname": "Liu",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "karen77777",
        "password": null
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "lastname": "Liu",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "karen77777",
        "password": null
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "lastname": "Liu",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "karen77777",
        "password": "123333"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "lastname": "Liu",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "karen77777",
        "password": "123333"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "lastname": "Liu",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "karen77777",
        "password": "123333"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "lastname": "Liu",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "karen77777",
        "password": "123333"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "lastname": "Liu",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "karen77777",
        "password": "123333"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "lastname": "Liu",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "karen77777",
        "password": "123333"
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "lastname": "Liu",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "karen77777",
        "password": "123333"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "lastname": "Liu",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "karen77777",
        "password": "123333"
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "lastname": "Liu",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "karen77777",
        "password": "123333"
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "lastname": "Liu",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "karen77777",
        "password": "123333"
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "lastname": "chenniuniu",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "chenniuniu@gmail.com",
        "password": "613387"
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "lastname": "chendada",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "chendaada@bobo.com",
        "password": "613387"
    },
    {
        "id": 19,
        "lastname": "chendada",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "chendaada@bobo.com",
        "password": "613387"
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "lastname": "VFVSD",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "DSFSDF",
        "password": "FDSFSDFDS"
    },
    {
        "id": 22,
        "lastname": "zhaohua liu",
        "firstname": "Jerry",
        "email": "zliu633@uwo.ca",
        "password": "613387"
    },
    {
        "id": 23,
        "lastname": null,
        "firstname": null,
        "email": "yche98@uwo.ca",
        "password": "613388"
    }
]
```

but got this when inspecting remotely on chrome

```
vendor.js:44729 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse
error:
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad
```

REEDIT:

Thank you guys for ur reply I'm new here to the community , you guys are the best.

I find out whats wrong here:

when I serve on the browser, I find that the response is correct as a json , like all of u guys said.
[response when serve on a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH3XY.png)

however, when I deployed the app and remotely test it on device:
I got the index.html as the response:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3ONj.png)

Comment: The data you get back from the Angular HttpClient is already JSON by default. You don't need to parse it again.

Comment: You seem to be getting back a JSON object then restringifying it and parsing it. thats probably why?

Comment: What is your exact output from the request, if you get the response that you mentioned in question `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` this shouldn't throw any error.

Comment: I'm receiving Objects instead of Json, the resonse is  [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] if I do console.log(data) without parsing.

Comment: your backend is not recognizing the request correctly and is retuning HTML - as you show in your screen shot, you then try to parse the html, the first character is '<'

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be getting back a JSON object then restringifying it and parsing it. thats probably why?

```js
   ngOnInit() {
      this.surgeonList = [
      ];
      console.log(this.value);
      this.httpclient.get('http://localhost:8080/users'
      ).subscribe(
          data => {
          this.surgeonList = data.map(doc=>{
          return {
              doc.lastname,
              icon: 'person'
            }
          })
              
              
          }
      );
  }
```

Comment: hi thank you ,  I tried the code , now I m sure that the problem is from JSON pase. and  I dont think the problem is with front end anymore , spring controller is not sending back valid  Json data .

Comment: not sure why that would be the case, if the json is the data you showed us on your post it creates a valid json object here is the ts interface of it:

Comment: declare module namespace {

    export interface RootObject {
        id: number;
        lastname: string;
        firstname: string;
        email: string;
        password: string;
    }

}

Comment: hi , I found that the response is indeed correct  when deployed on browser , but as long as I deployed the app, I got my entire index.html page as response. I ve attached those screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows :
Put `@ResponseBody` on your controller

```
@GetMapping("/users")
@ResponseBody
public List getUsers(){
    List users = userRepository.findAll();
    return users;
}
```

OR

```
@GetMapping(value="/users",produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List getUsers(){
        List users = userRepository.findAll();
        return users;
    }
```

OR 
Annonate your class with `@RestController`